# Angular momentum of an accretion disk

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

I need to plot the time evolution of the total angular momentum in an accretion disk. This confuses me because I thought this should be constant, since angular momentum has to be conserved?

I'm given the angular velocity $\Omega=(GM/R^3)^\frac{1}{2}$ where $M$ is the mass of the central object, and that the disk is made up of annuli of matter lying between $R$ and $R+ΔR$ with mass $2πRΔRΣ$, where $Σ(R,t)$ is the surface density at time $t$ (I calculated the surface density numerically at different times in the previous question, so I assume this has to be used in my answer).

So

a) Why does total angular momentum change?

b) How do I know what function of $R$, $Ω$, and $Σ$ represents total angular momentum?

c) I also need to plot the position of the "peak angular momentum surface density ($R^2ΩΣ$) as a function of time". Do I have to differentiate $R^2ΩΣ$ w.r.t. R and set equal to zero in order to find a maximum, and what does this actually represent?

Comment: The angular momentum of a system can change if momentum enters or leaves the system, for example if new material falls into the accretion disk from outside, or material in the disk disappears into the black hole.

Comment: The angular momentum of a *sub*-system can change.

Answer (score 1):

a) The total angular momentum of the entire system would be conserved in reality. However, the mechanisms by which angular momentum is conserved in accretion disks are rather complicated (viscosity and the creation of turbulent eddies). So if your model is very simple then the angular momentum may not be conserved.

b) Consider a ring of radius $r$ and mass $m$, the moment of inertia is
$$I=mr^2$$
and the angular momentum is
$$L=I\Omega$$
where $\Omega$ is the angular velocity. So this allows you to compute the angular momentum for a rotating ring. Then integrate to compute it for the entire disk.

c) The peak angular momentum density at time $t$ is
$$ P(t)=\max_{R>0} R^2\Sigma(R,t)\Omega(R) $$
If you have an analytical expression for $\Sigma(R,t)$ then we can possibly obtain $P(t)$ analytically. Otherwise you will need to iterate over all $R$ and find the maximum value numerically.

What you should find is that $P(t)$ initially decreases and then levels out at a constant value (possibly exponentially). This will show that mass density peaks have a tendency to 'spread out'. The function will also allow you to quantify the rate at which a newly formed accretion disk equilibrates.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I also need to plot the position of the "peak angular momentum surface density ($R^2\Omega\Sigma$) as a function of time". Would this be a 3d plot since time both time and $R$ vary? Do I have to differentiate $R^2\Omega\Sigma$ w.r.t. $R$ and set equal to zero in order to find a maximum? What does this actually represent? p.s. not sure what the etiquette is for asking a question in a comment - if you'd like me to post as a new, main question then let me know.

Comment: @AlexM I have updated my answer with a c) section, I suggest you update your original question with a corresponding c) question. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Excellent. Have updated original question.